# Locale variable socket referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I know there are other posts that are similar to mine but i did not get anything useful from those posts so here i go.

I have this code that i use:

```
def startElection():

  index = vesselList.index(getmyip())
  if index >= (len(vesselList)-1):
    neighbour = vesselList[0]

  else:
    neighbour = vesselList[index+1]
  try:
    socket = openconn(neighbour, destport, localip=None, localport=None, timeout = 5)
    socket.send(iD)
    socket.close()
  except socket.error, exc:
    print "Caught exception socket.error : %s" % exc
```

I get the error:

```
Exception (with type 'exceptions.UnboundLocalError'): local variable 'socket' referenced before assignment
```

I have tried changing the name of the socket. I have tried writing socket= None before the try method. Im not really sure why this is happening.

******** EDIT 1 ********

I have this code that is almost identical to the one i showed you guys first. This code below me works perfectly fine to run, no errors. When i uncomment the function call made to startElection() the code below me runs perfectly.

```
 #Start the for loop to send the new word to all the vessels in our vesselList. 
  destport = 63166
  for destHost in vesselList:
    if destHost != getmyip(): #Obviously we wont be needing to send it to the vessel it was made in. 
      try:
        soocket = openconn(destHost, destport, localip=None, localport=None, timeout = 5)
        soocket.send(userMSG)
        soocket.close()
      except soocket.error, exc:
        print "Caught exception socket.error : %s" % exc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation was that the port number was wrongly defined. A quick change on that fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You're using socket as a variable name and as a type.

The socket.error type is on the socket class. Because you've declared that socket is a variable, the runtime has probably created the local variable name with out a reference and then tried to use it to set-up the exception handler.

Change the name of the variable and the problem should go away.

Comment: I get the same error when changing it to e.g test1. I mentioned in my question that i did try to change the socket name. But thanks anyway

Comment: are you sure you changed all the instances of socket? The assignment, send and close - but not socket.error?

Comment: Yes everything. meaning four changes was made in my code.

Comment: @TimoCengiz There are just three occurences that should be local.  `socket.error` can't be changed unless you import the `socket` module under a different name but then using that name four times in the function has again the very same problem: you can't have a local name and accessing the same name at module level (unless explicitly using the module namespace to reference it).

Comment: @TimoCengiz - You've renamed sooket.error as well - you shouldn't do that - socket is being used by that type, including the socket.error. When you use socket to refer to an instance variable, you're hiding the socket implementation - leave socket.error alone, rename the others and you should be fine

Comment: But it works when im using the edited version. And im not importing socket so when i try to write socket.error it gives me error.   @RobertChristie

Comment: The problem was that the port number was bad. Thank you anyway.